# Laravel not serving files from public dir

Tags: php, html, css, laravel

I'm using the latest laravel 7.x.

The problem is: as the title says Laravel somewhy not serving things from public dir.
I have a picture in storage/app/public/img/Logo_original.png, and a css in storage/app/public/css/style.css

When I'm trying to get ether the css or the img, I get 404 error back from the server.

these codes ar present in app.blade.php:
css: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/style.css') }}">`

If I use the inspect element and check the sources ther is a css dir and inside a style.css file, but it is empty!

img: I've tried a lot of ways, but the last is:

```
@php
  $url = asset('img/Logo_original.png');
  print('<img src='.$url.'>');
@endphp
```

I've watched 4 tutorials, and 3 ways from stackoverflow, but unfortunately none of them helped me to solve it.

Please help me solve this mystery.

Comment: Did you creare symbolic link `php artisan storage:link`?

Comment: To get the correct public storage url use `Storage::disk('public')->url('img/Logo_original.png)` asset is used to serve files from `/public`

Comment: Did you try to add `storage` like so: `asset('storage/img/Logo_original.png');` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained in the official docs off [Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/filesystem), you need to:

1. Create the symbolic link from `public/storage` to `storage/app/public` using `php artisan storage:link`
2. Create an URL to the asset using `echo asset('storage/img/Logo_original.png');` including `storage` in its path. As the asset helper function will create an URL to the public folder. And the img isn't there but with step 1 above you've created a symbolic link called `storage` in the `public` folder. So the correct url would be `http://localhost:8080/storage/img/Logo_original.png` which can be created with the above mentioned

```php
echo asset('storage/img/Logo_original.png');
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I added storage/ to the link, and it worked!

Comment: For me it returns HTTP/0.9, I can't seem to solve it :(

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem while using Laravel Sail and Docker.

If you are creating your symbolic link using `php artisan storage:link`, Laravel will create the link using an absolute path, which wont work with your Docker container.

To solve this, you need to create your symbolic link using a relative path.

The `php artisan storage:link` command has a `--relative` option. Use this option when running your command. You might need to install `symfony/filesystem`, but you'll be prompted to do so if it's missing.

You can verify that you've created a relative symbolic link by `cd public` from your project root and running `ll`. You're storage directory should show the symbolic like this: `storage -> ../storage/app/public/`, assuming your linking `public/store` to `storage/app/public`, which is currently the Laravel default setup.